# Force WooCommerce to sell and ship to ONLY one state

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, woocommerce, checkout

How do I force WooCommerce to sell and ship to only one state? 
I can select a country but I can't find any way to allow selling and shipping only to one state/region.

Let's say I've selected only Canada and I want to sell only in Ontario. How can I achieve that? I probably have to add something to function.php to filter the states, but I don't know where to look for it...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this solution, but probably it's not the "cleanest" way to achieve this.

Any suggestion?

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_country', 'change_default_checkout_country' );
add_filter( 'default_checkout_state', 'change_default_checkout_state' );

function change_default_checkout_country() {
  return 'CA'; // country code
}

function change_default_checkout_state() {
  return 'ON'; // state code
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_woocommerce_states' );

function custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {
  $states['CA'] = array(
    'ON' => 'Ontario',
  );
  return $states;
}
```